# Overriding same signature from different interfaces

Tags: oop, interface, kotlin

in C sharp, if we have 2 interfaces, with the same signature method, we can implement them in one class, in the following way:

```
interface A 
{
 void doStuff();
}
interface B
{
 void doStuff();
}
class Test : A, B
{
void A.doStuff()
{
 Console.WriteLine("A");
}
void B.doStuff()
{
 Console.WriteLine("A");
}
}
```

If we thranslate this to Kotlin we have

```
interface  A
{
 fun doStuff()
} 
interface  B
{
 fun doStuff()
}
class Test : A, B
{
  override fun doStuff() {
            println("Same for A b")
                         }
}
fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
  var test = Test();
  test.doStuff() //will print Same for A b"
  var InterfaceA:A = test
  var InterfaceB:B = test
  InterfaceA.doStuff()//will print Same for A b"
  InterfaceB.doStuff()//will print Same for A b"
}
```

So, my question is, how can I
 give to each interface a different implementation as in C sharp example?. 
**Note: I have read the docs on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html , there is a similar example,

```
interface A {
 fun foo() { print("A") }
}
interface B {
 fun foo() { print("B") }
}
class D : A, B {
 override fun foo() {
  super<A>.foo()
  super<B>.foo()
     }
}
```

Here, foo is implemented in each interface, so when implemented in D, it just call the implementation defined in the interface. But how can we give define different implementation in D?.

Comment: Please reformat format your sample code (add indents)

Comment: is it better now @voddan ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in Kotlin. Kotlin is similar to Java in this respect. Methods that are override-equivalent in interfaces must have the same implementation in a class. The rationale behind that behavior is that casting a object reference to different types should not change behavior of its methods, e.g:

```
val test = Test()
(test as A).doStuff()
(test as B).doStuff() // should do the same as above
```

Comment: Altho that does not stand for extension functions :P